# unexpected output in recursive function involving static local variable

Tags: c, function, recursion

I am trying to find the output for fun(5). But I am getting an unexpected result (19) and don't know why.
My doubt is for n =5 for instance, it would return fun(3) + 3. After that would the return fun(4) + x work or the function fun will be called again?

```
int fun(int n)
{
   static int x = 0;
   if (n<=0) return 1;
   if (n>3)
   {
     x = n;
     return fun(n-2) + 3;
   }
   return fun(n-1) + x;
}
```

Comment: Your title says `c++` but the question is tagged `c`. They are different languages; please choose one.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks, corrected it.

Comment: Don't use `static`s in recursive function. It is defeating its purity.

Comment: When a function executes a `return` statement, control exits the function body.  This can get a bit confusing for recursive functions, but no, if the `return fun(n-2) + 3;` statement is reached then *that call* does not execute the `return fun(n-1) + x;`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that way answer comes out to be 4 but when i compile the code, the output is 19.

Comment: No, @MasterKas, that way the answer comes out to 19.  You are perhaps not appreciating the significance of "that call", or the order of events.  In order to execute the `return fun(n-2) + 3;`, the value of `fun(n-2)` must first be evaluated.  The `return fun(n-1) + x;` will be executed in that function call and two other more deeply recursing ones, but it is not executed after the `return` in the topmost call of the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sequence of what happens:

```
call fun(5)
  x=0; which, being the initialisation of a static local variable, 
       only happens before the very first call to fun()
  5>3: x=5 (not a problem, static vars can be changed and keep the value)
  return fun(3)+3
    return fun(2) + 5
      return fun(1) + 5
        return fun(0) + 5
          return 1
        return 1 + 5
      return 6 + 5
    return 11 + 5
  return 16 + 3
```

The exact meaning an relation of the following lines seem to be of interest to you.

```
static int x = 0;
/* Defines a local but static variable, initialised to 0;
   the initialisation happens before the first execution of the function,
   conceptually at the beginning of the whole program (credits John Bollinger).
   This does NOT cause an assignment to 0 during each execution of the function.
   The static attribute also means that the value at the end of one
   execution will still be found in the variable at the start of the next
   execution, even and especially if that start is before the end of the current execution,
   which is typical for recursive functions.
 */

/* ... */

x = n;
/* This conditional (inside an if) assignment in the middle of the 
   recursive function changes the value of the static variable away from
   the initialisation value, to e.g. 5.
   If/because no other assignment occurs, the value will stay in the
   for the rest of the program.
 */
```

Comment: But x is assigned value 0 at the beginning and being static how could we assign it value 5?

Comment: Exactly as in the code: `x = n;`. What problem do you see?

Comment: Why would that be a problem, @MasterKas?  Are you confusing `static` with `const`?  Or are you perhaps not appreciating that static initialization is a one-time event, logically occurring at the beginning of the whole program's execution?

Comment: That's why I commented above *not* to use `static` with recursions

Comment: @Yunnosch, it is inaccurate and potentially confusing to assert that the static initialization happens during the first function call.  As far as the language is concerned, it happens *before* the first call, at the very beginning of the program.

Comment: But x = 0 and being static, why does it get reassigned to 5? Doesn't it get fixed to 0 in the beginning itself.

Comment: `static` is initialized only once, on the program startup. Then it can be assigned anything.

Comment: @John  True, I did improve that.

Comment: @MasterKas As others have hinted, are you aware of the difference of `static` and `const` ?

Comment: according to my understanding  that's fine., but static value should not change if the global values are initialized

Comment: Which global values do you mean?

Comment: @Yunnosch static int x = 0;

Comment: A `static` local variable, if a new value is written (e.g. 5), should change. An attempt to write to a `const` variable should result in a compiler error.

Comment: What you quote I would not describe as "initialising a global value/variable". It is initialising a local though static variable, which afterwards can be changed by the function body.